# Laravel: make validation rule fail when using closure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-formrequest

Say I have a custom logic for validating the uniqueness of a `FormRequest` field, something requiring to find another resource in the database like below:

```php
class CreateMyResourceRequest extends FormRequest {
public function rules() {
        return [
            'my_field' => [
                Rule::unique('some_other_resource', 'some_column')
                    ->where(function ($query) {
                        $otherResource = SomeOtherResource::where(...)->firstOrFail();

                        // Process the retrieved resource
                    }),
            ]
```

The `firstOrFail()` call obviously makes the request fail with a 404 - Not found while I would like to return a 422 with a validation error on the field.

Is there a way to achieve this while still using the `Rule::unique()` provided by the framework?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Rule::unique()` is already sending validation error response, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As I said, I need to load another resource from the database in order to validate the uniqueness of one of the fields of the request. When doing so, I use the `firstOrFail()` method as I need to know that the referenced resource actually exists.. but that gives back a 404 rather than a validation error..

Comment: More generally, is there a way to make a rule fail when passing in a closure as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "your_field" => ["you_can_have_more_validations_here", function($key, $value, $cb) {

            $queryResult = SomeModel::find(1);

            if (someCondition) {
                $cb("your fail message");
            }
        }]
    ];
}
```

when the `$cb` run the validation will fail with 422

Comment: I've had a look at the other options but this is it probably, as it gives the most flexibility out of all. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ah, just for clarity if anyone else gets to read this, the callback doesn't prevent subsequent statements from executing, so if one has to break the validation logic at a certain point a `return` is needed

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `firstOrFail`, instead just use `first` and check if the output is null. If it is, return false.

Alternatively, the more Laravel way of doing it is:

```php
$query->leftJoin('otherresource', 'primarykey', 'foreignkey')->where(...)
```

Comment: I'm trying to return false at the beginning of the closure passed as parameter to the `where()` method and I'm expecting it to fail straight away.. but it doesn't. Are you referring to [the case when the rule is actually a closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures) rather than the one where a closure is passed to a rule?